# TFS - require tests to complete PR

Tags: tfs, build, pull-request, tfs-code-review

Our bugfix process (as - I guess - most of them) requires doing code review and manual verification by tester before completing pull request. We use TFS with git as VCS.

Is there a way to disallow completing PR before a manual tester approves the fix?

The only solution that comes to my mind would be by adding tester as required reviewer to PR, but this seems more like workaround rather than solution.

Comment: I think it's not bad solution. where the QA mark the tests (success/fail)? in tfs? qc?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, currently he moves test task in a story to column "Done" in TFS.

Comment: So maybe you can create a build that check the tests status or a external service that check it, and add a build validation / approval from external service validation